# Backing up Master-Master replicated MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I have two MySQL 5.5 databases which replicate each other. What's the best way to back these machines up? I would like to prioritise speed/ease of restoration.  Should I add extra slaves to both machines and also replicate there, and then periodically stop those slaves and copy the data somehow? Is a mysqldump enough, or should I be copying the whole data directory somehow?

Comment: If your concern is HA, but the two servers are sitting on the same earthquake fault / tornado plain / hurricane path / etc., it is not very HA.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Master/Master setup, so I would advise the following

- Do not mysqldump from either Master. Both Masters should be used as Active/Passive

  - Active : Receives all writes
  - Passive : Replicates from Active (Hot Standby for Failover)
- Add an additional slave from each Master

  - Can be low commodity in CPU since SQL thread processes one command at a time
  - Should have the same RAM and plenty of Diskspace for Backups

If you do go with additional slaves, you can use either mysqldump or xtrabackup.

Answer (score 0):

- Master master and write to both nodes? Recipe for disaster!! Avoid doing that.

Now points for answer:

- you don't need slaves to both nodes.  As they are in master master, slaving from 1 of them is fine.
- if one node is passive, configure backup there.
- if writing to both, create slave and setup backup there.
- You need logical backup? Use mysqldump.
- all innodb? Large db? Use xtrabackup.
  Check out [how to setup xtrabackup with Holland framework.](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/setup-and-configure-mysql-backup-using-holland-and-xtrabackup). physical backup restore will be faster than logical as db grows.

Comment: +1 to this, however, if for some reason your mysql servers are running on Windows then it's only mysqldump for you or maybe mydumper run from a linux server, but not xtrabackup :)